# Is it a good idea to run dynamically generated code on my GPU with the use of OpenCL, or there are better ways?

Tags: c#, matrix, optimization, calculation

### Introduction

So, let me introduce a problem. Currently, I'm writing a program in C# that has a lot of computations in it (more precisely it's a neural network lib) and by far I've used standard arrays to store matrixes, but I thought of it's better to create a 2d, 3d matrix class to encapsulate all matrix operations I need and then clean loops in my code.

As you may know, it's pretty easy to accomplish with basic [operators overloading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-sharp-operator-overloading/), but I came around another problem, it would be slower than regular for loops over arrays, as in the case you have a big equation, intermediate classes which are produced by overloading of operators may cause overhead. I googled it and found [the article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3354/Efficient-Matrix-Programming-in-C) that turned out to be very useful for me. In short, the writer uses additional classes to first create an equation tree, second compile it in a C# method with the use of MSIL (Microsoft Intermediate Language) solves the equation at once.

But then I thought of the possibility of running matrix calculations on my GPU, as it will be even faster. I came around a NuGet package Cloo that uses OpenCL and [a wrapper for it](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1116907/How-to-Use-Your-GPU-in-NET) (I'd like it to work on any video card not only NVidia with its CUDA) to run C code on your GPU, but it as I've just said it uses C code that has to be written as a string.

### Question

Finally, my question. Is it a good idea to generate the C code string dynamically, from the equation tree, to calculate my optimized equations on a GPU or there are other ways to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, right answer for your question - implement both ways and write the [benchmark](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet). Because we don't know, what GPU is used, what CPU is used, what matrix size, etc.

Theoretically, GPU should be faster if you are able to use [SIMD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD)/[SIMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_threads) approach without branches (e.g. without `if`s). So if you can write planar code which operates internal arrays, then GPU (event embedded) will work faster. However, the main word here is **theoretically**.

Practically:

- .Net-based (and JVM-based) code is much simpler to support.
- OpenCL code works different for NVidia/AMD/Intel GPUs (because sometimes you can store a lot of data in the [local memory](https://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/register_spilling.pdf), sometimes you couldn't; sometimes you can rely on fast GDDR6, sometimes videocard (for example - embedded) just shares computer RAM).
- Some GPU memory profiling requires video freeze (to mitigate fluctuations). And you will have many other interesting items during the GPU development.

However to help you:

- Try [Tensorflow Matrix multiplication](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/linalg/matmul) first. It [has .Net bindings](https://github.com/SciSharp/TensorFlow.NET) and it can do mathematics operations on both CPU and GPU.
- Compare .Net code with native, for example - Rust/Kotlin Native/C++. Probably you can just move all computations into the native part (all these options are much simpler than OpenCL coding and supporting).
- From my prospective (no proofs here, sorry) it is much simpler to write code on multiple languages than generate code at language X from language Y.